# Passing struct data type to named pipes in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, named-pipes

I found one sample program that passes string from client to server in named pipes. How can I pass a struct data type through named pipes in c++?

WriteFile function of client looks like this:

```
WriteFile(hPipe,TEXT("Hello Pipe\n"),12,&dwWritten,NULL);
```

ReadFile function of server looks like this:

```
while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, &dwRead, NULL))
```

The structure I need to pass looks like this:

```
struct EventLogEntry 
   {
       string date;
       string time;
       string subsystem;
       unsigned long eventType;
       string majorFunction;
       string messageText;
       unsigned long timeStamp; //Added for TimeZone Corrections
   };
```

In `CreateNamedPipe()` I'm using `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` `PIPE_READMODE_BYTE` pipe mode.  Do I need to change them to `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` and `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`?

Comment: `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` can't be used with `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`. 
You need code to call `CreateNamedPipe` and `ConnectNamedPipe` on your server to wait for your client connection. If the connection succeeds then loop to call read from the pipe to get the client message (i.e your struct data) process it then write back to your pipe to tell it about the input request.
This is an example, looks very easy to understand.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server

Comment: I know they can't be used together. What I meant to say is, should I replace PIPE_TYPE_BYTE and PIPE_READMODE_BYTE both with PIPE_TYPE_BYTE and PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE respectively if I'm sending struct data.

Comment: If those are `std::string` objects, you had best devise a *protocol* for marshaling their data over that pipe, because you certainly aren't going to just send it by address or reference. That's a recipe that will simply not work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass instances of a class across the wire.

You basically have two options.

A) Use fixed size buffers:

```
struct mydata {
  char message[200];
  char name[50];
  int time;
};
```

and just send `sizeof(mydata)` across the pipe.

B) Marshal the data in a different format:

```
struct mywiredata {
  int messageoffset;
  int nameoffset;
  int time;
  char buffer[ANYSIZE_ARRAY]; //blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043
};
```

Here you basically have a fixed header portion with all the strings stored as bytes at the end. You find the start of a string by accessing the buffer at the appropriate offset. You need marshalling code at each end of the pipe to convert to/from your `EventLogEntry` and `mywiredata` structs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on first method?

Comment: The first method should be pretty easy, you just copy `mylogdata.messageText.c_str()` to the correct field with something like `StringCchCopy` and at the other end you just do `mylogdata.messageText = pipestruct.message;` This is basic C++ and is not pipe specific.

Comment: I'm new to programming word so can you provide any sample program that is passing struct over pipes or some links that I can refer to? @Anders

Comment: @Mayank If you can't do it even now after being told how by Anders (who explained it in the most simple way possible for you to understand), you may as well focus on more practice with programming and come back to it later on when you have more XP under your belt, otherwise you'll end up spending loads of time only to get an buggy implementation which will fail on you sooner or later. Alternatively, look for open-source libraries which offer IPC support via a few helper routines you can just call and be done with it (there's many around on places like GitHub, just do a search for it).